# Google App Script - How to monitor for new users

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api

I wondered if anyone could point me in the right direction here?

I want to monitor the Google Workspace estate, and when a new user has been created send them an email.  I’ve looked through the APIs but nothing is jumping out at me. But I know there are 3rd party tools out there that do this, so there’s got to be something I have missed?

Comment: take a look on https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/watch#EventType.    But you should have admin access to do so.

Comment: Thanks @liquidkat, that looks like it would do the trick. But I've not had much exposure/experience with HTTP requests with Apps Script. I shall take a look and see what I can figure out!

Answer (score 1):

I just created this script in Google Apps Script which gets and prints the list of all the users that were created today.

You can use this as a guide and keep testing with it. To accomplish this I used the Reports API to get the admin logs and get the list of all the users that were created today.

```
function myFunction() {

      var userKey = 'all';
      var applicationName = 'admin';
      var optionalArgs = {
      eventName:'CREATE_USER',
      startTime: "2022-03-23T12:00:00.000Z",
      fields : "items.events.parameters.value"
  };

      var rep =  AdminReports.Activities.list(userKey,applicationName,optionalArgs);
      const A = (JSON.parse(rep));
      var totalUsers = Object.keys(A.items).length;

      for(var i=0; i<totalUsers; i++)
      {
        var userEmail = A.items[i].events[0].parameters[0].value;
        Logger.log(userEmail);
      }
      
}
```

You would just need to change the `startTime` value according to the date you need to use and implement the part of sending the email now that you have all the email addresses.

#### References

- API method: [activities.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/reference/rest/v1/activities/list)
- Apps Script reference: [Reports API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-reports)